# Get an value from IN clause query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find a way to get a value from the IN clause in my query.
The column I am looking for is "viewURL" in the table "contentAvailability".

```
$availableProvidersSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contentProviders 
                WHERE 
                code IN (SELECT providerCode FROM contentAvailability WHERE contentGuid = '".($row['guid'])."')
                ORDER BY firendlyName") or die(mysql_error());

                while($availableProvidersRow = mysql_fetch_array($availableProvidersSQL)) {

                        echo '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding-bottom:7px;">
                        <figure>
                        <a href="#"><img src="'.$baseURL.'images/providers/'.$availableProvidersRow['code'].'/Logo.jpg" class="providerLink"></a><br />
                        </figure>
                        </div>';

                }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The question is a tad unclear. Could you share your tables structures, some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for that sample?

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column contentGuid is common to both contentAvailability and contentProviders, then why not use a JOIN?

```
SELECT 
    pv.*, 
    av.viewUrl 
 FROM contentAvailability av 
 JOIN contentProviders pv ON pv.contentGuid = av.contentGuid AND av.providerCode = pv.code 
WHERE av.contentGuid = $row['guid']
ORDER BY av.friendlyName
```

If contentGuid is NOT common to both tables, then you can do a JOIN like this:

```
SELECT 
    pv.*, 
    av.viewUrl 
 FROM contentAvailability av 
 JOIN contentProviders pv ON av.providerCode = pv.code    
WHERE av.contentGuid = $row['guid']
ORDER BY av.friendlyName
```

Please let me know if there's something I'm missing.

Edited to show case where contentGuid is not common to both tables.

Answer (score 0):

This query has got a little confused, this should work

```
$availableProvidersSQL = mysql_query(
           "SELECT * FROM contentProviders 
            WHERE 
            code IN (
                      SELECT providerCode 
                      FROM contentAvailability 
                      WHERE contentGuid = '{$row['guid']}'
                     )
            ORDER BY firendlyName") 
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Remember if you are using a double quoted string scalar variables are simply expanded to their value, but when using an array you either have to forget the quotes around the array occuranec like `" $row[guid] "` or use `{}` around the array like I have above.

But

> Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
>   is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: JOIN would be great, But I answered the questions as asked. OP is obviously learning, so I decided not to blast them with options and confuse.

Comment: @Strawberry I imagined OP was on the chapter that was teaching them about the `IN()` clause, therefore an answer suggesting the use of JOIN would just be irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.columns
     , x.I
     , x.actually
     , x.want
  FROM contentProviders x
  JOIN contentAvailability y
    ON y.providerCode = x.code       
 WHERE y.contentGuid = '{$row['guid']}'
 ORDER 
    BY x.firendlyName;
```

Note that 'firendly' isn't a word.